# Best way to make selects in laravel?

Tags: laravel, fluent

In order to use the Form::select, you need to add a name and two arrays.

In a normal case, we have one with the id and another one with the name. Both needs to be loaded from a query.

So in the model I have something like this:

```
public static function get_ids()
{
    //return DB::query('select id FROM __roles');
    return DB::table('roles')->get(array('id'));
}

//Returns an array with all the names
public static function get_names()
{
    //return DB::query('select name FROM __roles');
    return DB::table('roles')->get(array('name'));
}
```

However, this gives me this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 ) )
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => '1'  [id] => '2' [id] => '3' )
```

For the form

```
Form::select('role', array(Role::get_ids(), Role::get_names()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
public static function get_ids()
{
    //return DB::query('select id FROM __roles');
    return DB::table('roles')->get(array('id'))->to_array();
}

//Returns an array with all the names
public static function get_names()
{
    //return DB::query('select name FROM __roles');
    return DB::table('roles')->get(array('name'))->to_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this option:

```
 $projects = Project::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->lists('name', 'id');
```

In template:

```
{{ Form::select('project', $projects) }}
```